# Preventing race conditions using Java

Tags: java, hibernate

My background is as a PHP dev so I'm not quite sure how to handle this race condition I've been having trouble with using Java servlets, and the hibernate framework.

Basically, I'm trying to prevent double submits of payment requests on the backend. When the payment request comes in I check the DB for the customer's current payment status. If it's "UNPAID" I update DB to "PROCESSING" and continue to process the payment finally setting it as "PAID" when everything is complete.

However, I believe hibernate isn't running my DB updates until the session closes. That means if a second request comes in before my first payment request has finished processing it will process the payment request a second time.

In PHP I would just check and update the payment status as soon as the payment page was hit and I never experienced any problems with race conditions doing that. However, this pattern I've used previously isn't working in the Java environment I'm developing in.

Does anyone have an idea as to what the right way of doing this would be?

Comment: The answer to this would be way to complex and broad for stackoverflow. If you want to prevent reading from your database when it's in a dirty state you should use the database lock system.

Comment: Could you not provide a little more information? I have very limited experience with Java and "the database lock system" isn't something I've came across previously.

Comment: Servlets should be written as if each request is single threaded.  Make your database writes transactional with the appropriate isolation level.  It'll work.  Start with the JDBC tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Record_locking or https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html

Comment: Whatever you have been doing in PHP, you should be able to do in Java.

Comment: Can you post some sample code to show how you're doing your transactions?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description, I would say your PHP code has hidden race conditions and you just don't realize it. You need to tackle this from a different angle. Give up the assumption that you can prevent double submits and instead *assume they're inevitable*. Once you realize this is true, you can build an appropriate design (which will probably be a lot different than what you've currently got). If you can post your schema and some sample code, I might be able to offer some suggestions.